# Real Mathematics in Video Games

Tags: puzzle, applications

Out of curiousity (and perhaps also to amuse my students), I am looking for examples of actual mathematics appearing in video (computer) games.
Of course that sort of mathematics would probably be very basic, but perhaps it still exists.

To clarify, I mean some use of mathematics in-game, as opposed to the design or programming of the game. I also prefer examples of games which are not purely puzzle games, but perhaps contain some puzzle solving. Nevertheless, such examples would also be interesting.

I hope this question is not off-topic. I was considering asking on Arqade SE, but I don't suppose there are many mathematicians there...

Thanks!

Comment: There's a game called [2048](http://2048game.com/). But then again, it can be considered a _purely_ puzzle game.

Comment: This question might be relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170407/videogame-dota-2-probability#comment2385142_1170407

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Yeah, I know it, but is there a winning strategy (I think that would be equivalent to having an actual mathematical solution)? I've always used a strategy which is not mathematical (but works with high probability).

Comment: The Knights of the Old Republic (don't remember if it was the first or second) had a [Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) puzzle. Also pretty sure one of them also had a "move liquid to this bucket to that bucket using 3 and 5 gallon buckets" type puzzle. Also pretty sure Mass Effect had one of those too. Maybe I am actually thinking of Mass Effect actually... I wouldn't be surprised if both series had the same sort of puzzles, as for the most part they were made by the same developers (except KoTOR 2)

Comment: If you don't include basic calculations as mathematics, then I'd venture there's _very_ little outside of ingame puzzles. Otherwise examples abound; e.g. collecting only items with a high enough value to weight ratio, determining the damage outputs of weapons with different attack rates or bonuses or cooldowns, etc. You'll find these aspects in just about any RPG.

Comment: All the motion games are requiring "unintentionally" use of mathematics/physics to "calculate" location-speed;acceleration and from there predict action. The user implement manually "filters" that allow him to get desired results.